# Cant build. Cant clean. Could not find viewmodel.aar (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, jcenter

When i Clean or build my project, this error pops up:

Could not find viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0).

https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/viewmodel/1.1.0/viewmodel-1.1.0.aar

[image]

and this in SYNC tab:

[image]

UPDATE:
this is my BUILD.GRADLE
[image]

[image]

Comment: have you added `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version" `

Comment: what version do you suggest?

Comment: use the latest possible for you.

Comment: i placed implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0' and it gives me error. sorry im still beginner in android studio

Comment: are you using kotlin with your project?

Comment: post your build.gradle code with your question it will be helpful.

Comment: where to find the latest version for viewmodel:lifecycle. can you give me a link sir?

Comment: check my update in the post sir. ive put the build.gradle there

Comment: you can update your build tools version and android studio will show if there is update available for you. like it is showing you for firebase in this app.

Comment: How can i update build tool version sir @KaranMer?

Comment: My android studio is up to date btw

Comment: there is buildToolsversion in first photo of your build.gradle. you can update it with latest available and check.

Comment: i changed it to 28.0.0, same error happened

Comment: I would recommend to post code and remove posted images as it is showing your app id and signing details which can be used against you.